# Replace the set of characters with special characters in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Source:

```
<txt>
    &lt;Data&gt;
    &lt;div class="label"&gt;
        &lt;span&gt;Welcome&lt;/span&gt;
    &lt;span id="UserName"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;.
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/Data&gt;

</txt>
```

Output required:

```
<Data>
<div class="label">
    <span>Welcome</span>
<span id="UserName"></span>.
</div>
</Data>
```

Rule:
I want to replace

```
&lt; with <
&gt; with >
```

There  are other characters also, for simplicity I have mentioned two only.

I am not sure how to search for a string in xslt and replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using **disable-output-escaping**

```
<xsl:template match="txt">
   <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

That should give you the output you require.

Comment: Yes. disable-output-escaping is deprecated and is heavily criticized because people often misuse it. But extracting "escaped XML" from a node of an XML document is one use case where it is a respectable solution. Just make sure your transformation is used in an environment where disable-output-escaping works - that is, an environment where the XSLT processor is serializing the output (rather than, say, writing the output to a DOM).